# PhpStorm configuration to see more rows?

Tags: phpstorm

How to configure PhpStorm to show me more rows .. Examples:

[image]

So same code in Atom (and other editors):

[image]

Same code, but other editors show me more code (rows) PhpStorm - 14, Atom - 23. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Goto settings ->Editor ->Colours and Fonts-> Font tab there is line spacing option decrease that to 1 or <1 then you can see more rows on screen .

Comment: I am happy to help :)